# PowerEdge 2950: Can E2118 result in E1422

Tags: hardware, dell-poweredge

The past few days I've been setting up a used Dell PowerEdge 2950 server. It's been running fine until just now, when it suddenly stopped while running a fairly heavy task (`svnadmin verify`). The LCD was and is showing the following message:

`PowerEdge 2950   E1422 CPU Machine Chk   E2118 Fatal NB Mem CRC`

Now, the memory error E2118 seems straightforward. One of the banks is probably broken. I'm running memtest right now.
**Update**: Well, memtest didn't find any errors, so it's not *that* easy.

E1422, less so. Is this likely a separate problem, or just a result of E2118? Googling for this code says "update the BIOS" which isn't very specific as to the cause of the problem.

Comment: You're probably going to have to contact Dell to get the definitive answer here.

Answer (score 2):

`E1422 CPU Machine Chk` means that the CPU detected an hardware error and stopped operations. It can be related to the other error - memory problem.

You can see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine-check_exception) and [here](http://lists.us.dell.com/pipermail/linux-poweredge/2011-March/044490.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If the CPU or memory is having an issue, such as a voltage regulation problem, then it could drop voltages on the shared bus between the memory and the CPU and fault them both.  I was reading some release notes last week for different model Dell server (maybe an R710) where issues can be caused by Intel SpeedStep changing the CPU speed and there being a delay before the memory adjusted speed.   This set up a condition where there could be a fault in the time between.  In that particular case, a BIOS update addressed that issue.

Run a CPU benchmark and a memory benchmark to see if you can recreate the fault.  If so, maybe you can narrow it down to one component or the other.